# Pythonnet crash on line from import

Tags: c#, python-2.7, python.net

After recompiling the solution project of pythonent accordance with the procedure oleskii for the .NET framework 4, I'm having a problem with my code. Here are the first few lines where the crash occurs.

```
import sys, clr

sys.path.append ("G:/bin_EESPORt")
clr.AddReference ("ASAM.HILAPI.Implementation")
clr.AddReference ("ASAM.HILAPI.Interfaces")
clr.AddReference ("dSPACE.HILAPI.EESPort")
clr.AddReference ("dSPACE.HILAPI.EESPort.Interfaces")


from System import *
from System.IO import *
from System.Threading import *
from ASAM.HILAPI.dSPACE.EESPort import *   #here crash pythonwin
from ASAM.HILAPI.Implementation.EESPort.Error import *
from ASAM.HILAPI.Interfaces.EESPort import *
from ASAM.HILAPI.Interfaces.EESPort.Enum import *
from ASAM.HILAPI.Interfaces.EESPort.ErrorFactory import *
from ASAM.HILAPI.Interfaces.EESPort.ErrorObjects import *
```

So in Debug mode my tool PythonWin crash (It freezes and raises an error pywin32) on line:
from ASAM.HILAPI.dSPACE.EESPort import *   #here crash pythonwin

The Pc system is windows 7 64-bit.
The IDE is PythonWin with python 2.7.9 MSC v.1500 32-bit (Intel)] on win32.
The Frameworks installed are: .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, .NET Framework 4 Extended, .NET Framework 4 Targeting Multi-Pack and Visual C # 2010 Express.

Thank you in advance deposit for the help, I really need your help.

Comment: did you try with latest python.net from github or pypi?